# How to keep a task running in task scheduler despite password change

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, taskscheduler

I have a windows task running on windows server via Task scheduler. It is scheduled to run indefinitely. When the server password is expired after set period or is changed, the task stops running and then we have to change the password in task scheduler for keeping it running. Is there any way we can remove this dependency of password in task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing I think would work is to connect it to some password manager, and read from there (I know we did something like this with https://www.passwordstore.org/)
then you only need to have your own accepted gpg keys to read from there